# How can i replace function's derivation to values?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, taylor-series

Function which is include  deriative like :

df = -2*x*y(x)*Derivative(y(x), x) - y(x)**2

I have got Derivative(y(x), x)'s value but i don't know  how to subs

```
x= sp.symbols('x  ')
y=sp.Function("y")(x)
f = sp.Function("f")(x,y)

f = -x*y**2

f_num = f.subs([(y,1),(x,2)])

df = sp.diff(f,x)

# I have to calculate df_num value by using(subs) respect 
x,y,Derivative(y(x), x)
```

thanks everyone who is helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you mean?

```py
import sympy as sp

x= sp.symbols('x')
y=sp.Function("y")(x)
f = sp.Function("f")(x,y)

f = -x*y**2

f_num = f.subs([(y,1),(x,2)])

df = sp.diff(f,x)
df = df.subs(sp.diff(y,x),1)

sp.pprint(df)
```

Comment: i'm trying to use Taylor's series expansion for numerical methods.İ'm figure it out i'm going to share final version when code is working thanks for your support

Comment: Thanks for finally giving me 50 rep :D

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary differential equation is giving me f and i tried to solve this problem numerically by use cubic Taylor's series expansion(TS3). Initial values are known x=2 and y =1 and we are trying to find function's values at x = 2.5.

```
x= sp.symbols('x ')
y=sp.Function("y")(x)
f = sp.Function("f")(x,y) # f is actually y'(derived of y )
x0 = 2
y0 =1
f = -x*y**2  # ordinary differential equation and its derivatives line 33 to 35
df = sp.diff(f,x)
dff = sp.diff(f,x,2)
y_num = []
h = 0.1 # step size
k = 0
while x0<2.5:
    f_num = f.subs([(y,y0),(x,x0)])

    df_num = df.subs(y.diff(x),f_num).subs([(y,y0),(x,x0)])

    dff_num = dff.subs(y.diff(x,2),df_num).subs(sp.Derivative(y, 
    x),f_num).subs([(y,y0),(x,x0)])

   y_num.append(y0 + h*f_num + h**2/2*df_num+h**3/6*dff_num)

   y0 = y_num[k]
   x0 = x0+h
   k=k+1
print(x0)
print(y_num)
```

I don't know this is a useful post or can i express myself correctly but thanks for all interest and answers

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when doing subs when derivatives and functions are present. The short answer is:

```
df = f.diff(x)
df_num = df.subs([(y.diff(x),1), (y,1), (x,2)])
```

where the derivative (which depends on y) is done before y and y (which depends on x) is done before x.

Additional comments: 1) note that you define f as f(x, y) and then immediately afterwards define it as the expression `-x*y**2`; the first definition is not necessary. 2) you define `f_num` but this has no impact on calculating the numerical value of `df`.

Comment: f_num impacts df_num values not directly df thanks a lot for your answers